# trimming images using Nirsoft SiteShorter

Tags: image, jpeg, screenshot, crop

I'm using a Windows command line utility called **SiteShorter** from 
[NirSoft.net](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html)

The problem I'm having is that the images have a border around them.
There is a switch called **CutWebPage** that I *think* will trim around the edges, but I can't make it work like I want.

An example of the command lines I'm using:

```
siteshoter.exe /url http://www.example.com/reportpdf/p2457155140435.html /Filename c:\test\screen1.jpg /BrowserHeight 1000 /DisableScrollBars 1 /BrowserTimeout 1000 /CutWebPage 1 /CutLeft 25 /CutTop 30 /CutWidth 900 /CutHeight 900
```

My question is how to use the CutWebPage switch correctly. Thanks.

[image: notice border around edt of picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These arguments works for me:

/BrowserWidth 964 /BrowserHeight 484 /ImageSizePerCent 50 /CutWebPage 1 /CutLeft 2 /CutTop 2 /CutWidth 960 /CutHeight 480

Make sure that your 'BrowserWidth' is 4 pixels wider than your CutWidth. Add Cutleft value 2, CutWidth value is [BrowserWidth - 4px] and CutHeight value is [BrowserHeight - 4px].